# How to create a temporary table in a postgreSQL function which has columns names and amount that are generated dynamically by the function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, temp-tables

I have created a postgreSQL function which queries data from a time series database to provide a defined result. The function has two arguments: apartment id and day.

The function does the following:

- it finds the amount of rooms of a defined apartment
- it finds the ids of all the rooms of the apartment
- it finds the values related to a certain metric for the defined apartment and the defined day and calculates a SUM aggregate for each room
- it returns an array containing the calculated metric aggregate
- the room ids are contained in a separate array

The function is copied below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fetch_rooms_energy (apartment INTEGER, day TEXT)
RETURNS FLOAT []
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    number_of_rooms INTEGER;
    room_ids INTEGER[];
    room_energy FLOAT(6);
    rooms_energy FLOAT(6) [];
BEGIN
    SELECT count(DISTINCT roomid) INTO number_of_rooms FROM periodic_measurements WHERE apartmentid = $1 AND roomid != 0;
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT roomid INTO room_ids FROM periodic_measurements WHERE apartmentid = $1 AND roomid != 0 ORDER BY roomid);
    FOR counter IN 1..number_of_rooms LOOP
        SELECT SUM(mvalue) INTO room_energy FROM periodic_measurements WHERE (apartmentid = $1 AND roomid = room_ids[counter] AND metric = 5 AND mtimestamp::TEXT LIKE $2);
        rooms_energy = ARRAY_APPEND(rooms_energy, room_energy);
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'room ids: %', room_ids;
    RAISE NOTICE 'rooms energy: %', rooms_energy;
    RETURN rooms_energy;
END;
$$;
```

This is the result of running the function:

```
=> SELECT fetch_rooms_energy (1931, '2023-04-01%');

NOTICE:  room ids: {18360,18361,18362,18363,18364,18365,18366,18367}
NOTICE:  rooms energy: {0,21340.555,21559.266,60753.023,46735.54,14539.594,22325.67,NULL}
                                     fetch_rooms_energy                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {0,21340.5546875,21559.265625,60753.0234375,46735.5390625,14539.59375,22325.669921875,NULL}
(1 row)
```

If I use this other command, I am able to get the result as a set of elements rather than as an array, which is a bit closer to the result I want to get:

```
=> SELECT UNNEST(fetch_rooms_energy (1931, '2023-04-01%'));

NOTICE:  room ids: {18360,18361,18362,18363,18364,18365,18366,18367}
NOTICE:  rooms energy: {0,21340.555,21559.266,60753.023,46735.54,14539.594,22325.67,NULL}
     unnest      
-----------------
               0
   21340.5546875
    21559.265625
   60753.0234375
   46735.5390625
     14539.59375
 22325.669921875
                
(8 rows)
```

However, I **need to get the output of this function in table format** as shown below in order to use it in my data visualization platform:

```
 room 18360 |      room 18361      |      room 18362       |        room 18363         |        room 18364         |      room 18365      |      room 18366       | room 18367 
------------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------
          0 | 21340.55396146954036 | 21559.265370118024581 | 60753.0229418996635052412 | 46735.5408051978938452581 | 14539.59331341666434 | 22325.669210315860839 |           
(1 row)
```

So, I would need to copy the result of the room_ids array into the column names of a temporary table and the content of the array rooms_energy into the values of the first row of such a table. Then I should change the table as the returning object of the function.

Is there a way to do this?

Any hint is appreciated!

Note that:

- each apartment might have a different number of rooms so **the amount of columns is known only after the function has found it**
- the **columns names are knows only after the function has found them out**
- the **temporary table shall exist only for the time the function is running**

I am running PostgreSQL 14.9 on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Bernardo

Comment: It's not possible in a single step because the output structure of a function needs to be known at call time. You can first let the function dynamically build the structure and save it to a table, then fetch the data from that in the second step. You can run a function that figures out the structure and (re)defines another function for you to call in second step, or let the function produce two columns and use crosstab to pivot them. If `returns setof record` sounds appealing, keep in mind that while it enables output record structure to change, it forces the caller to know it up front

Comment: Please post sample input data and the expected results of that data - as text, **no images**. For  a good way of creating textual data see [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).  Additionally post table definitions (ddl). Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Something to consider. Instead of your function returning an array have it return a "table" of 2 columns: (id, energy). SQL is very good at that. Then let your app's presentation manager format the final result as your want. SQL is very very poor at that, but app should handle it easily.

Answer (score 0):

On relational databases more common way to handle data like that would be to have two columns `roomid` and `room_energy`.

And what's best there's even no need for complex loop logic in the function. This could be queried with a single query.

My best try to accomplish the same logic as your example:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fetch_rooms_energy(apartment int, day text)
RETURNS TABLE(roomid int, energy float)
LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (roomid)
    roomid,
    (
      SELECT sum(mvalue)
      FROM periodic_measurements b
      WHERE
        a.apartmentid = b.apartmentid
        AND a.roomid = b.roomid
        AND metric = 5
        AND mtimestamp::TEXT LIKE $2
    ) room_energy
  FROM
    periodic_measurements a
  WHERE
    apartmentid = $1
    AND roomid != 0
  ;
$$
;

SELECT * FROM fetch_rooms_energy_(1, '2023-09-22 12:00:00');
```

This produces the following result:

```
 roomid | energy
--------+--------
      1 |
      2 |    8.5
      3 |    8.5
```